# Replacing a verbose code block using native methods (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to learn the included methods with Rails and coming across situations where it seems like there should be better/cleaner ways of completing the same task, but I'm not sure how to improve.

The one I've hit most recently is as follows, where I have an array of hashes passed in as a parameter. If the array has less than 5 elements then I initialize elements until there are 5 total.

```
def do_stuff(numbers)
  raise "Maximum of 5 numbers can be defined in numbers array." if numbers.count > 5
  blank_range = (numbers.count-1)..5
  if blank_range.count > 0
    blank_range.each do |i|
      numbers[i] = {"entry" = " "}
    end
  end
end
```

This is a very basic example of what I'm wanting, though it's a pattern I've found myself using a few times. Is there a way of doing this built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think method `#fill` is what you need. It takes three arguments - an object to append to array and a range to fill with that object.

```
numbers.fill({ 'entry' => ' ' }, numbers.size...5)
```

So `{ 'entry' => '' }` is your object, `numbers.size` is a starting position and `5` is the end position.

If `numbers.size` is 5 it doesn't fill in anything.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-fill

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby documentation for the `Array` class would be a great place to start.  There you'll find different ways to construct and manipulate arrays.

For example, to construct an array of 3 single space strings:

```
[" "] * 3         => [" ", " ", " "]
Array.new(3, " ") => [" ", " ", " "]
```

You could then use `+` to concatenate arrays like `Array.new(3, " ") + numbers`.

The Array class includes `Enumeration`, as does `Range`.  When constructing an array from something else, `inject` can be useful.

Something like `(1..3).inject(numbers) { |numbers, i| numbers.unshift(" ") }`

Or maybe `3.times { numbers.unshift(" ") }`